# How to connect my Spring Boot app to a database (MySQL) not in the same network?

Tags: mysql, database, networking

I used to use like this : **spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/nameDB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true** to connect backend to the database, but now I want to use another network for my database. When I replaced localhost by the address of the network, it generates error. I'm not sure if I'm using the right address, should it be IPv4 ?

I want to know how to resolve my problem.

Comment: In order to be able to help you, you need to provide more information. Error text, MYSQL environment (docker, k8s), how do you specify the address? The more important details, the better.

Comment: I'm using xampp server for the databases. Well I'm not sure what address to put in host address so I may use the wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change bind address in your server.

(linux)path for mysql: `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf or /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

`bind-adress = 127.0.0.1` (you should change this area for your server IP)

`port = 3306` (your port for mysql you should let for another server or all )

for ufw => `sudo ufw allow from REMOTE_IP_ADRESS to any port 3306`

and you can connect to mysql server.

and remote user acces you should do for mysql

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE_NAME.* TO USER@'IP_ADDRESS' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_PASSWORD';
```

and you should set update db for access

```
update db set Host=IP_ADDRESS where Db=DATABASE_NAME;
update user set Host=IP_ADDRESS where user=USER;
```

Comment: How can get the server IP ?

Comment: if that database exist in your server, your ip is server's ip
if you want access to db from your local network. you can set your configuration and then you can let to your local ip for db.

please provide more information for i can assist to you. 
For example where is DB? on your local? on server? where do you want to access DB? On your local? on your another server? provide me your scenarios, please.

Comment: I'm trying to run my database server on my PC, and the back-end will be in a raspberry pi so connected to another network.

Comment: I got it. Rasperry PI if connected same network with PC you can open gateway and you can open with host. for example you can open 192.168.1.105 for Rasperry Pi. that is your remote ip. and you can open for another host for your local PC. Rasperry PI should be able access your local PC from gateway. And your local IP host is your DB IP. That's all. If you do not know open host and check gateway. you can write 'ipconfig' on terminal for windows. or you can write "netstat -nr | grep default" on terminal for mac os. for more information please check local gateway, host, tcp/ip ...

Comment: How to configure the devices to allow communication between them. I get always this error  :  Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=IPADDRESS)(port=3306)(type=primary). Connection timed out: no further information.

Comment: Did you configured your Rasb.PI for access? You can check this page for ras.pi https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/remote-access.html
please configure your device. and then request to rasberry pi from your local.